# adding an uiviewcontroller who's uilabel is not changing

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I'm adding a UIViewController which has only an UILabel to the main UIView. I create it like this:

```
WEPopoverLabel *contentViewController = [[WEPopoverLabel alloc] init];
[contentViewController setContents:@"aaa"];
```

(The hole code .m):

```
if (!self.popoverController) {

        WEPopoverLabel *contentViewController = [[WEPopoverLabel alloc] init];
        [contentViewController setContents:@"aaa"];
        contentViewController.lContent.text=@"aaarrr";

        self.popoverController = [[[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];
        self.popoverController.delegate = self;
        self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(50.0f, 20.0f);
        self.popoverController.passthroughViews = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sender];
        CGRect rectForPopover = [self.view convertRect:sender.bounds fromView:sender];

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rectForPopover inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown) animated:YES];
        [contentViewController release];
    }
```

Well, WEPopoverLabel is being created because it shows up in my window and also executes setContents because I've got a NSLog which is printing in my console.

However, the label is not being changed. This is the content of WEPopoverLabel:

```
@interface WEPopoverLabel : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel * lContent;
}
-(void)setContents:(NSString *) theContent;
```

and .m

```
@implementation WEPopoverLabel

-(void)setContents:(NSString *) theContent{
    lContent.text = theContent;
    NSLog(@"texto fijado");
}
```

In the .xib, I've connected the lContent to File's owner.

Why is not being updated the text of UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UIViewController, have you connected the main view in the xib to the file owner as well as connecting the label?

Also have you added WEPopoverLabel to the view after it is created:

`[currentView addSubview:contentViewControler]`

I would give the label a background colour so you can tell if it is actually beng displayed.

Comment: The view is being displayed because the label has a default text and it's visible. And yes, i'm adding the uiview with this:   self.popoverController = [[[popoverClass alloc] initWithContentViewController:contentViewController] autorelease];

Comment: could you post the entire .m file?

Comment: Of course, edited the first post with more info. My label has as default text "Label" and it's not changing anyway

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that lContent isn't being connected correctly. Inside setContent could you do: if (lContent) NSLog(@"not null") and see if it prints?

Comment: it prints... Definitely it has to be a IB connection problem (i tried to change the label.text in viewdidload without success) but I'm not capable to see the error. File's owner is connected to the view and uilabel aswell... they are displaying correctly in the app but the label settle is not working!

Comment: you don't have any statements like lContent = [[UILabel alloc] init] inside your WEPopoverConent do you? IBOutlets are initialised for you.

Comment: Wow! I added an [[UILabel alloc] init] some time ago and deleting it now it's working! thank you Ian!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setContents:(NSString *) theContent{
lContent = [[UILabel alloc] init]    
lContent.text = theContent;
   NSLog(@"texto fijado");
}
```

thats correct. check this:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1002736

Or

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lContent;
```

and in this method:

```
self.lContent.text = theContent
```

Comment: I thought it was going to be the right answer but it's not. I've put that line in viewdidload but still not changes in my UILabel...

Comment: also tried adding the properties and using self.lContent.text but still not working... :S

Comment: You have to make property. Then synthesize it. and then in your method set whatever you want. and remember about `self.something`

Comment: I know, it's also synthesized and i'm using the "self". I've even tried with self.lContent.text = @"whatever" and also setting it from the main view as contentViewController.lContent.text = @"whatever". but... still nothing! don't understand why is this happening...

Comment: I did mini app, and everything is working. Firstly I've made label as property. then synthesize, next in IBAction i did self.label = @"something" and everyting was OK. So maybe you don't have connected outlet or something. oh i have idea, make WEPopoverLabel subclass of UILabel

Comment: Thanks Wojtek, I got it solved with Ian's answer and properties and synthesized calls!